# Image stitching 6x6 images

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, accord.net

I am trying to stitch together very large mosaic images in C#. I've tried using the EmguCV C# libraries but there is a serious problem in that apparently (?) you cannot disable 'wave correction' from C# which causes memory overload (related post/discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978108/opencv-emgucv-big-image-stitching)).

Questions:

1. Basically, is there any way to turn off the wave correction (set the option to 'false') from C# ??
2. Can anyone point me to working C# stitching code for very large mosaicing? My application is very simple it's just scanning so there is no distortion, equal overlaps, etc., but it has to be pretty close to pixel-accurate. I've looked all over the net and can't find anything for larger mosaics.

More comments:

1. I've tried using Accord.NET but it appears to be only 32 bit code thus won't work for large images. Must be 64bit. I'm really kind of shocked that Accord.NET is not 64bit unless hopefully i'm missing something...
2. I've tried using openCV directly using C++ but can't mix it with my year-long development of my main code in C#. I tried making a dll in C++ but I'm no good at C++ and couldn't seem to even get it close to working.
3. I would like to be able to stitch 10x10, 3000x2000 pixel images. I've got plenty of ram, up to 32Gb if needed.

Thanks very much for any info.

Comment: You said you've tried stuff so show what you have tried and someone can help, Also if you're just adding multiple images why not use graphics directly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for response. If you look at the link I provided in the original post, you will see the code that I've tried. It's basically just from the examples given in EmguCV and OpenCV. 

It's not just adding multiple images, you need to do some matching and blending that's not trivial. I assumed EmguCV would work 'fine' but there's major problems as I've described and in previous post.

Comment: stitching is usually done by **SIFT/SURF + RANSAC** so I would start by resizing your images to smaller ones like 300x200 ... find stitching for that (in sub-pixel) and apply on the original resolution images. If you got problem even with simple merging of images (just pixel copy with transform)  then you probably should learn more about programing or seriously debug your code...

Comment: I don't have problem positioning images. IMHO artifact-free blending of irregular seams and normalizing illumination/levels is challenging. Reducing to thumbnail size will not work because features are very small/fine. I understand your critical last comment but would have preferred an answer to any of my questions... I don't want to re-invent the wheel if something good already exists.

Comment: Welp, no useful answers. Oh well.

Comment: Have you got answer

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var stitcher = new Stitcher(false))
{
     stitcher.WaveCorrection = false;
```

Not sure if still an issue, but this helped.